# Multiple docker-compose files with gitlab shell runner

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am trying to maintain `dev`, `test` and `master` environments on the same host by using Gitlab CI.

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /-no-ci$/
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "test"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"

before_script:
  - cp /home/gitlab-runner/my-app/.env.$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH ./.env.$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  - echo '' >> ./.env
  - echo 'export CI_COMMIT_BRANCH="${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}"' >> ./.env.$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  - "cat .env.$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH | envsubst > .env"
  - source .env
  - "cat Dockerfile.template | envsubst > Dockerfile"
  - rm .env.$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH Dockerfile.template
    
build-master:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - sudo docker-compose build 
    - sudo docker-compose up -d 
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - master
  
build-test:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - sudo docker-compose build 
    - sudo docker-compose up -d 
  only:
    - test
  tags:
    - test

build-dev:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - sudo docker-compose build 
    - sudo docker-compose up -d 
  only:
    - dev
  tags:
    - dev
```

Since I have to start three containers (`webserver`, `db` and `pgadmin`), I use `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.1'
services:
  webserver:
    build:
      context: ./
    restart: always
    image: my-app/${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
    container_name: my-app-webserver-${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
    volumes:
      - ${PATH}:/app/${PATH}
    ports:
      - ${WEBSERVER_PORT}:${WEBSERVER_PORT}
    depends_on: 
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.2
    restart: always
    container_name: my-app-db-${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_DB_DATA}:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.18
    restart: always
    container_name: my-app-pgadmin-${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 80
    ports:
      - ${PGADMIN_PORT}:80
    volumes:
      - ${PGADMIN_DATA}:/var/lib/pgadmin/
    links:
      - "db:pgsql-server"
    depends_on: 
      - db
networks:
  default:
    name: my-app-network-${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
```

On the host I have `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "my-app-shell-prod"
  url = "https://gitlab.my-app.com/"
  token = "abcdefgabcdefg"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    privileged = true 
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]

[[runners]]
  name = "my-app-shell-test"
  url = "https://gitlab.my-app.com/"
  token = "abcdefgabcdefg"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    privileged = true 
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]

[[runners]]
  name = "my-app-shell-dev"
  url = "https://gitlab.my-app.com/"
  token = "abcdefgabcdefg"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    privileged = true 
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

My initial thought was to use three different shell runners with tags `master`, `test` and `dev` to maintain independent builds, for each having a corresponding `docker-compose.yml`.

When I push to `dev`, pipeline is passed successfully and I have three containers with names `...-dev` running. However, if I merge `dev` to `master`, another pipeline is passed, but now I have only three `...-master` containers running (but in the same time job logs show that `-dev` have been restarted).

```
...
134 $ sudo docker-compose up -d
135 Recreating my-app-db-dev ... 
136 Recreating my-app-db-dev ... done
137 Recreating my-app-webserver-dev ... 
138 Recreating my-app-pgadmin-dev   ... 
139 Recreating my-app-pgadmin-dev   ... done
140 Recreating my-app-webserver-dev ... done
```

I found [an article](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) on overriding `docker-compose.yml` files. However, when I try to use `-f` in `.gitlab-ci.yml` script section, it shows help message in job logs where no `-f` option is presented.

```sh
# docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
```

**The question is**: how to maintain `docker-compose` logic without using `-f override.yml`? Just create three versions of `docker-compose.yml` in three folders and use `[entrypoint]` in `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

**Update**
Why do I refuse to use `docker:dind`? I can not find the right way to run a job that starts docker-in-a-docker since again you need three `docker-compose.yml` files just to start `docker:dind` containers. Am I missing something?

Comment: Currently I made three folders `dc-files/master`, `dc-files/test` and `dc-files/dev` with empty `.keep` files (to enable git to store them), and copy `docker-compose.yml` to one of these directories based on the branch (and corresponding runner). I believe there is a better solution.

Comment: Irrelative to the topic but still... I also found that two (or more) `pg-admin` containers on one host are blocking each other preventing any connection, so I build only one `pg-admin` on `dev` branch.